# In Android Annotations, i want to know when a @background finish

Tags: android

In Android Annotations, trying to do a API Request[Login] with @background and ProgressDialog to notify the user is doing the login.

```
@RestService
AuthInterface loginClient;

@Background
void login() {
    loggedUser = loginClient.login(new Login(getUsername(), getPassword()));
}

@UiThread
void showProgress() {
    progressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "please wait...", true);
}

@UiThread
void hideProgress() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method annotated with `@UIThread` is called after the background has finished. In your case you want this one to be executed after the `@Background` has finished:

```
@UIThread
void hideProgress() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

So your other method - `void showProgress()` should NOT have the `@UIThread` annotation and should be called when the user initiates the action, for example in some `onClickListener` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, i put hideProcess() into Login() but now the progressDialog dont Dimiss

Comment: find the answer in the documentation of android annotations here is the link [link] https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/769#issuecomment-26655312